# How to interrupt executor thread

Tags: java, concurrency, executor

What the right way to interrupt executor's thread?
I've got this:
Thread class with name Worker with method:

```
public void run() {
    while(!(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        System.out.println("work " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
    }
}
```

And main class with:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
Worker worker = new Worker();                   
executorService.execute(worker);
```

I try to call `worker.interrupt();` or `executorService.shutdownNow();` but my thread goes on and isInterrupted() is false.

Comment: Check this out which might be a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142665/why-does-thread-isinterrupted-always-return-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post all the relevant code? Based on the information you have given, I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. See below a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that works as expected - output:

> work pool-1-thread-1:false
>   work pool-1-thread-1:false
>   work pool-1-thread-1:false
>   ....
>   Thread has been interrupted

Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        executorService.execute(worker);
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static class Worker extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("work " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            }
            System.out.println("Thread has been interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your code is work fine, the difference from mine, that in Worker class in run method I work with JMS. Just one line `messageService.sendMessage(message);` If i comment it, thread stops, if not its always `work pool-1-thread-1:false`. And I can stop thread just with my own flag instead of isInterrupted()